# When are ALL the cases when the onSaveInstanceState() method called?

Tags: java, android

All the sources I read have all mentioned couple of cases and concluded with "a few other cases". What are ALL the cases when the onSaveInstanceState method called in a View/Activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) says

> This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever there is as soft kill of the activity. I.e when the orientation changes or when the process is killed by android due to low memory.

It's not called when the user knowingly just navigates away from the activity.

Refer to this link: https://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/saving-instance-state

Answer (score 7):

onSaveInstanceState() will be called by default for a view if it has an id.

google said: "The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy **that has an id**".

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: While this is accurate information, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Also be aware that `onSaveInstanceState` can be called on a fragment directly after `onCreate` (`onCreateView`, `onActivityCreated`, `onStart`, and `onResume` will NOT be called), if the fragment is attached to an activity but not shown, then destroyed.  Thus you need to be sure that everything you reference in `onSaveInstanceState` is initialized in `onCreate`, otherwise you risk a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I've an app where I see NPEs in onSaveInstanceState on an object which is initialized in onCreate. This is really weird and can only make sense if onSaveInstanceState gets called before onCreate. Do you have any clue as to why that can happen?

Answer (score 3):

- onSaveInstanceState() is  called when there is an orientation change
  or user presses home button.
- If there is an another    activity in front of an
  activity and the OS kills the hidden activity    in order to free
  memory(or when memory is needed elsewhere), then onSaveInstanceState() is     called so  activity can save its state information which is restored using onRestoreInstanceState() when user start that activity next time .
- Default views of Android save their state via a call to
  View.onSaveInstanceState which is restored by the default implementation of onRestoreInstanceState

As per [doc](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html)

> If the user interacts with an activity and presses the Back button or
>   if the finish() method of an activity is called, the activity is
>   removed from the current activity stack and recycled. In this case
>   there is no instance state to save and the onSaveInstanceState()
>   method is not called.
>
> If the user interacts with an activity and presses the Home button,
>   the activity instance state must be saved. The onSaveInstanceState()
>   method is called. If the user restarts the application it will resume
>   or restart the last running activity. If it restarts the activity it
>   provides the bundle with the save data to the onRestoreInstanceState()
>   and onCreate() methods.
>
> If you override onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() you
>   should call the super implementation of it, because the default views
>   of Android store their data via a call to View.onSaveInstanceState
>   from the onSaveInstanceState() method of the activity. For example
>   EditText stores its content via the default call of this method.

Answer (score 1):

This method did not call when user presses "return" button,this is one of that case..

Answer (score 1):

onSaveInstanceState is called when ever activity is out of veiw.. like when u press home key, onSaveInstanceState is called.

Comment: It is not called _every_ time an activity leaves the view. Like when a user presses back to leave the activity.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://medium.com/@lylalyla/onsaveinstancestate-gets-called-regardless-of-whether-or-not-your-app-process-is-killed-93bb760379cd): the answer is `onSaveInstanceState()` gets called regardless of whether or not your app process is killed. So in all of these scenarios, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called:

**Normal background scenario**

1. Your activity goes into the background and `onSaveInstanceState()` is called
2. You do some other things
3. Your user navigates back to your activity

**Process kill background scenario**

1. Your activity goes into the background and `onSaveInstanceState()` is called
2. You do some other things and during this time the system starts running low on resources and closes your app’s process
3. Your user navigates back to the activity
   `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` (with the saved instance state bundle) are called

**Configuration change scenario**

1. A configuration change occurs and `onSaveInstanceState()` is called
2. `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` (with the saved instance state bundle) are called

The difference is whether `onCreate()/onRestoreInstanceState()` are called. In the process kill and configuration scenarios they are called. In the normal scenario, there is no need to recreate the activity and neither are called.
Note that `onSaveInstanceState()` is called when your activity goes into the background and NOT when the app process is about to be killed. This is because in the scenario your app process gets killed, the system is pretty resource constrained as is and it would NOT be a good time to spend cycles storing key/value pairs in RAM.