# Android - first app onCreate null parameter

Tags: java, android, mobile

I start develop app for Android. I have some code write in Eclipse and I use attached emulator. When I send porgram to my emulator I get some error.
Debugger show in line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` `// savedInstanceState = null`

My code

```
public class PushAndroidActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try
        {   
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: could you please show the complete code and LogCat output?

Comment: In LogCat I don't see any error:/

Comment: In the question you say "I get some error". So what is exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Yes, now I filetered log i have NullPointerException, but I don't know why, where

Comment: OK, now we've established you are actually getting an error, I'll ask again. WHAT IS THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE?

Comment: There is my message: E/AndroidRuntime(480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sagar.gcma/com.sagar.gcma.PushAndroidActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please also give us the next lines in the crash log (the full stacktrace) so we can see exactly where this error is occurring.

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just try rotating your device - left ctrl F11. you will realize that the bundle is != null

onSaveInstanceState() will be called by default for a view if it has an id. The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy that has an id. You could check these :

[savedInstanceState is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554317/savedinstancestate-is-always-null)

[When are ALL the cases when the onSaveInstanceState() method called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678062/when-are-all-the-cases-when-the-onsaveinstancestate-method-called/7023241#7023241)