# Activity onCreate() savedInstanceState is null

Tags: android, android-activity

I have application with Activity, where `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("XXX", true);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then I'm doing the steps:

1. Start my application.
2. Press device 'Home' button (going to Android main screen).
3. Go to list of applications and press my app icon.
4. My application is shown again.

I expect, that after restarting `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate()` will contain boolean "XXX". But `savedInstanceState` is null. **Why it is null?**

I have tried set activity's launchMode attribute to any value ('standard', 'singleTask', 'singleTop, 'singleInstance') - it doesn't affect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [savedInstanceState is always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554317/savedinstancestate-is-always-null)

Comment: pressing the home button will not cause your app to be terminated and thus `onCreate` won't be called again.