# Keeping objects onPause()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a lot of trouble with Android Fragments, and I don't know why.

I want to keep an object in memory whenever I pause the app (onPause()).

I have a MapView with some layers. And I want to keep those layers, so the map doesn't have to reload from scratch and recreate them whenever I pause and resume the app.

The thing is, I can't save them with onSaveInstanceState(). They are objects, not primitives. They are also from a library, so I can't make them implement Serializable or Parcelable.

I want to find a solution without resorting to:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

to my Activity, since it is considered bad practice. Also, it doesn't work for when you pause and resume the app.

I also tried

```
this.setRetainInstance(true); // retain this fragment
```

on my fragment's onCreate(), but I would also like to avoid it. It doesn't work anyway.

After much trial, error and testing, I found out that my fragment's onSaveInstanceState() doesn't even run. I can't even keep a simple boolean whenever I pause and resume the app.

I read:

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating

[savedInstanceState is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554317/savedinstancestate-is-always-null)

Amog many other posts and, of course, the Android documentation.

Some of my code:

Creating the fragment:

```
    navFragment = FragNavigation.newInstance(); // keeping the reference to the navFragment

    // setting up the viewpager
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vpMainViewPager);
    MainPagerAdapter mainAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    mainAdapter.addFragment(navFragment);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
```

Trying to save a simple boolean in the instance state (remember: this doesn't even run):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: is map loaded? " + mapIsLoaded );

    outState.putBoolean("mapIsLoaded", mapIsLoaded);
}
```

And trying to load it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRetainInstance(true); // retain this fragment

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: null? " + (savedInstanceState == null) );

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mapIsLoaded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mapIsLoaded", false);
}
```

What am I missing? I'm clearly not understanding something. Why is it so hard to keep values when you pause the app?

Comment: Did you know when onSaveInstanceState method is called?

Comment: What do you mean? It never gets called. That's part of the problem.

Comment: as i know its called when device orientation is changed .But you wrote on your question is that u are trying to save object on onPause

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But it is supposed to be called when you pause the app as well. Else, how am I supposed to store data when the app is paused and resumed?
How do you use to do this? i bet you had a similar problem already.
Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: i have added answer.please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing the MapView layers using a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) as per Architecture Components. If that is not an option, you can manually store and retrieve objects using the Activities [getLastNonConfigurationInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance()).

Comment: Cool. Never knew about ViewModel. Gonna look into that and come back to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it worked for the rotation. Not for pausing and unpausing the activity. Why is this so hard? Isn't this a standard operation?

Comment: Pausing/Resuming an Activity wouldn't cause them to become GC'd unless you have calls in the start of the lifecycle that inadvertently overwrites them?

Comment: No. I have no such thing. I'll make a test application tomorrow to really figure this out. As I said, I'm probably missing somehing very obvious. I need to read some more.

Comment: I ended up using a static private object that extends ViewModel and encapsulates all map elements. In the fragment's onCreate(), I instantiate the ViewModel if it is null, and, if it's not, I read all map elements from it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        /**
         * store your data 

         */

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        /**
         * retrieve your data       
         */



        super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean store my data on sharedPreferences? Because you can only save primitives and serializables in sharedPrefs. And it's not ideal. I mean, all I want is to prevent map reloading.