# savedInstanceState Bundle is always null in onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin

My requirement is to save some state in the bundle before my application goes to onDestroy.
And read the state in onCreate using bundle and update the state accordingly
i am using below code to save the state.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("SCORE_KEY",10)
}
```

onSaveInstanceState getting called when i am pressing Home Button from the Application.
But when i relaunch the application , onCreate is getting called but the Bundle is null.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("Log", " onCreate savedInstanceState : $savedInstanceState")
}
```

How can i make use of savedInstanceState without getting null

Comment: Please, format correctly your question, it's pretty hard to understand what and where the problem is

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: @LijithRajan There are some use cases of how `onSaveInstanceState` works. To trigger it you can turn on `Do not keep activities` in developer setting of phone.
Post that run the app and put the app in background and return to foreground. You will find the data printed.
[document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` after `outState.putInt()` because **you first need to add your `int` and then call the `super`** to save the state, like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) { 
    outState.putInt("SCORE_KEY",10)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554317/savedinstancestate-is-always-null)

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putInt("SCORE_KEY",10)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("Log", " onCreate savedInstanceState : $savedInstanceState")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```