# onSaveInstanceState is not saving my values ( onCreate input Bundle is always null )

Tags: android, android-activity

Saving bundle (activity A):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("test", "value");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Navigating to activity B;

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), B.class));
```

Going back to activity A:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), A.class));
```

Trying to load the value I wrote to bundle in activity A:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

Log.d("MY", "saved instance is null"+ Boolean.toString(savedInstanceState == null));
}
```

Returns always savedInstanceState = null. What I'm missing here?

**onRestoreInstanceState is never triggered when I return to main activity**

Comment: -1 ? For what? Have tried everything and by android API everything should work, but its not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I don't seen an answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Try rotating the device when on activity A. You will see the following in the Log, which means your onSaveInstanceState() is working fine:

```
saved instance is nullfalse
```

Here are an excerpt from the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html), which you may find interesting:

> The callback method in which you can save information about the current state of your activity is onSaveInstanceState(). The system calls this method before making the activity vulnerable to being destroyed and passes it a Bundle object. The Bundle is where you can store state information about the activity as name-value pairs, using methods such as putString(). Then, if the system kills your activity's process and the user navigates back to your activity, the system passes the Bundle to onCreate() so you can restore the activity state you saved during onSaveInstanceState(). If there is no state information to restore, then the Bundle passed to onCreate() is null.
>
> Note: There's no guarantee that onSaveInstanceState() will be called before your activity is destroyed, because there are cases in which it won't be necessary to save the state (such as when the user leaves your activity using the BACK key, because the user is explicitly closing the activity). If the method is called, it is always called before onStop() and possibly before onPause().

Comment: `... Then, if the system kills your activity's process and the user navigates back to your activity, the system passes the Bundle to onCreate() ...` - isn't my activity killed when user navigates to another activity?

Comment: Try logging onDestroy() :-). No, in this case, it isn't.   A new instance of the Activity is being created every time the line startActivity(...A.class) is running.

Comment: Yes, you'r are right. Reference: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png To sum up: **Activity gets stopped when user navigates to another activity. Activity doesn't get destroyed until system says so (for example not enough memory).**

Comment: You can change the OS behavior so the activity is destroyed as soon as it's no longer on the screen. This is useful for debugging purposes. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8621269/483708

Answer (score 6):

I got this solve by having:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

when re-launching the old intent that has the saved state from background.  Without this flag, I think that when startActivity is called, it creates a new instance of the Activity instead of getting the old one from the stack.

Comment: But the savedInstance is always null for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) before adding content to it.

Comment: Nope, not working. And I'm quit sure that the `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` has to be at the end. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Comment: It hast to be at the start. Maybe this was not the OP's issue, but just clarifying that it indeed is the first thing you should call.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter as long as you don't add anything to the outState with an ID that overlaps anything from the OS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342274/call-super-onsaveinstancestatebundle-first-or-last

Comment: @blindstuff Not according to Android's [documentation and code examples.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState)

Answer (score 2):

If navigating to another Activity and coming back, best way is to save it to `SharedPreference` in the `onPause()` method, which is bound to execute when a new activity is loaded. On the other `Activity`, the value can be accessed in `onCreate()` by accessing the shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to retain the state of your fragment over a rotation of the device and you wonder that `onSaveInstanceState` is never called:

1. Check whether you call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` in all your `onSaveInstanceState` functions.
2. Check that you don't have `android:configChanges` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app is running on Lollipop (API21) version of Android or newer, your

```
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState);
```

will NOT be called as it simply does not exist on earlier versions of the platform than 21. To support pre API 21 devices you must, instead of the above, override the following method:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState);
```

This will work on API 21+ as well, so you do not need to override both methods, of course (unless you know you need to deal with PersistableBundle the new one offers).

(Copied because it worked for me)
Source: [onSaveInstanceState is not getting called after screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549722/onsaveinstancestate-is-not-getting-called-after-screen-rotation)