# Fragment setRetainInstance(true) save View properties

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I'm confused about the best practice for saving the states of Views that live inside of fragments in Android.

I thought that `setRetainInstance(true)` would do the trick; however, while this does retain the old global `View` references declared in the `Fragment`, those Views will not be used when inflating the layout. Thus, I have to manually transfer the properties from the old global View references to the new Views in the inflated layout. See the code below for how I'm doing this.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    // I need to save the state of two views in the fragment
    ProgressBar mProgress;
    TextView mText;


    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // savedInstanceState == null if setRetainInstance == true
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain the instance between configuration changes
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup c, Bundle b) {
        // Inflate xml layout for fragement (orientation dependent)
        View v = i.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, c, false);

        // Grab Views from layout
        ProgressBar tmpProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        TextView tmpText        = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        // If View References exist, transfer state from previous Views
        if(mProgress != null){ 
            tmpProgress.setProgress(mProgress.getProgress());
            tmpText.setText(mText.getText());
        }

        // Replace View references
        mProgress = tmpProgress;
        mText     = tmpText;
        return v;
    }
}
```

It's my feeling that `setRetainInstanceState(true)` should mainly be used for keeping a fragment alive so that background processes can maintain a connection to it. If that's the case should I not be using this method to retain the states of my `View`s?

**More specifically:**

1. if `setRetainInstanceState` is `true`, is the above code the best way to retain the `View` states between orientation calls?
2. If I'm not interacting with background tasks, should I just use `setRetainInstanceState(false)` and use `Bundle`s to maintain the View states? (Note: [bundles cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13009676/1290264) if `setRetainInstance == true`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setRetainInstance` DO NOT keep your view in memory just keep same instance as a kind of `Singleton` based on `tag` or `ID` that you give to your fragment. It's good because when you `Fragment` goes to background your view is destroyed and not unecessary memory.

Answering your two questions:

1. Do not keep your view created! Recreate your view every time onCreateView is called. To keep states and more use global variables.
2. No, once you set it your `Fragment`, Android OS will keep same instance for same tag or ID so when it goes to background keep in mind to save your `Bundle` with view state at `onSaveInstanceState` to recover view status at next time.

Read more about Fragments lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

And about `onSaveInstanceState`, see more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

For example you could do something like that:

```
package com.example.stackoverflowsandbox;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static String VIEW_STATE_A = "a";
    public static String VIEW_STATE_B = "b";
    public static String VIEW_STATE_C = "c";

    private String       currentState = MyFragment.VIEW_STATE_A;
    private View         view;

    public void changeStateTo( final String newState ) {
        if ( this.currentState != newState ) {
            this.currentState = newState;

            this.updateViewState( this.currentState );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        this.setRetainInstance( true );

        this.view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.my_view, null );

        this.updateViewState( this.currentState );

        return this.view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        this.view = null; // release the reference to GC

        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    private void updateViewState( final String state ) {
        // do what you want to do with your view here...
    }
}
```

Change your `fragment` state by `changeStateTo`.

Comment: The problem is that `onSaveInstanceState == null` if `setRetainInstance` is `true` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13009676/1290264). Therefore, bundles are only useful if `setRetainInstace` is `false`

Comment: So use global variables @bcorso!

Comment: Don't you claim in your answer that this is "bad practice"?

Comment: Yes but I didn't know about `NULL` `Bundle` when `setRetainInstance` is `false`. So global variables I saw is only way because became almost a `singleton`.

Comment: hmm, so can you give an example using the basic code example I gave to show what you would change?

Comment: So basically, instead of storing the entire `View` in memory, only save the variables relevant to the state. So in my example, I would use  `int mProgress` and `String mText` instead of `ProgressView mProgress` and `TextView mText`?

Comment: Yes @bcorso you will save memory and processing. E.g. save progress and text value in `onDestroyView`.