# Bundle savedInstanceState is null on onCreate() although savedInstanceState is already set data

Tags: android, bundle

I have a problem when getting state of activity. I have 2 activities: MainActivity and Activity2. In MainActivity I have put an `editText` and a `button` name GO. In Activity2, I have a `button` name `BackMainActivity`. What I want is that: I put a text, for example:"abc" into EditText then click button GO. App will navigate to Activity2. After that, I click button BackMainActivity, app will navigate to MainActivity and data in EditText is restore as "abc".
    I already used onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. App run through onSaveInstanceState  before going to Activity2. But if I go back to MainActivity, onCreate(), savedInstanceState is null. Can you show me the reason ? I want to store data of mainActivity in bundle. So how can I do ? Thank you very much !

MainActivity

```
package com.example.demosavedataactivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText t;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a =  t.getText().toString();
        outState.putString("text",a);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        t.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onRestart");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Activity2

```
package com.example.demosavedataactivity;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    Button back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

activity2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CombackA1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem..i tested your code ..it works well.

Comment: What i want is that: input string like "abc" into editText in mainActivity. Then click GO button to go to Activity2. In Activity2, click button BackMainActivity to come back MainActivity. And in MainActivity, it still keeps the text "ABC" in editText. In fact, editText is null :((. Do u know why? I already explain my problem in the above question. Thank u in advanced.

Comment: I have the same issue, actually all the answers about this question can't solve. I thinks it's a basic problem, but why it's confused?

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like:

1: Fetch data from `onSavedInstanceState` in your `oncreate()` and put it in your `edittext`. Something like:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    /*Just fetch data from savedInstanceState */
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
         t.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
    }
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);              
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
```

And in your `Activity2` set a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag with your intent.like:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
 startActivity(intent);
```

For a better idea just check this [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320785/onsaveinstancestate-is-not-saving-my-values-oncreate-input-bundle-is-always-nu).

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick function of your Activity2 you don't go back to the previous MainActivity but you open a new MainActivity.

Just finish Activity2 by calling finish() then your first MainActivity will come up again. It should be working with the hardware back button of your device.