# onSaveInstanceState is not getting called after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I know there are lots of quetions regarden onSaveInstanceState but I wasn't able to find an answer to my problem.

I have an activity that extends AppCompatActivity; this activity uses 3 fragments and it has a variable 'int currentStep' to track which fragment is being displayed. In the onSavedInstanceState method I store the currentStep variable in the bundle, and then in onCreate method I restore it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String CURRENT_STEP_TAG = "current_step";
    private int currentStep;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedido);        

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            loadFirstFragment();
        } else {            
            currentStep = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_STEP_TAG);
            if(currentStep == 2){
                //Do some stuff...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        Log.d("deubg", "--------onsaveinstancestate--------");
        outState.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_TAG, currentStep);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

 ...

}
```

The thing is that onSavedInstanceState won't get called when screen orentation changes, and according to google documentation, it should. The message  "--------onsaveinstancestate--------" doesn't show in the console.
However the Bundle savedInstanceState in the method onCreate is non null after screen rotation, but it doesn't have the int 'currentStep'.

I've tried many things: changed AppCompatActivity for ActionBarActivity, moved the call for super.onSavedInstanceState to different locations, tried to store other variables; but no matter what I do the method doesn't execute.

Also I DO NOT have android:configChanges in my manifest.

My application is being compiled against sdk version 22, buildToolsVersion 22.0.1

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Unless your app is **running** on Lollipop (API21) version of Android or newer, your

```
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState);
```

will **NOT** be called as it simply does not exist on earlier versions of the platform than 21. To support pre API 21 devices you must, instead of the above, override the following method:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState);
```

This will work on API 21+ as well, so you do not need to override both methods, of course (unless you know you need to deal with `PersistableBundle` the new one offers).

[See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that there was a newer version of the mehtod. It works fine now.

Comment: Another question, will onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState); get called in a device running android API21+? or do I need to override both methods?

Comment: Yes, it will be called. No need to override both

Comment: Nice!That is the answer.

Comment: phenomenal - has been on this problem for a while - but that is clear

Comment: I am finding still that protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) is not called all the time.  I am using the latest vs.net android emulator and similarly i am unable to get the current active fragment consistently.  I am currently using api 19

Comment: @David if you are sure it's not your bug then simply post a question with code snippet so we can see what are you doing and possibly help figuring out why you face problems you describe.

Comment: I just made a test it doesn't work for API21, you need API22 and above.

Comment: It's documented as "Added in API level 21", so either you found a bug or your tests are simply broken.

Comment: @Skemello Not working in API 21 for me either. Did you ever figure out why?

Comment: Actually, docs say: `This is the same as onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) but is called for activities created with the attribute persistableMode set to persistAcrossReboots`