# Simulate backstack savedInstanceState behaviour

Tags: android, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I want to test the state of my app when it's left in the backstack for too long.

When I open like 20 apps one after the other my last used app (which is the app I'm testing) eventually terminates and a savedInstanceState occurs. Is there a way to simulate this behaviour for the app I'm testing without having to open another 20 apps in order to burry my app in backstack?

Comment: You can change orientation.http://stackoverflow.com/a/15048112/909956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple way to do it. Just enable *Do not keep activities* under *Developer options*. Your activity will then be immediately destroyed as soon you leave it and `onRestoreInstanceState()` will be invoked when you return.

Alternatively, you can force a configuration change (like orientation) and that will recreate your activity too. One issue with this approach is that there's a bug with some JellyBean/KitKat versions where the emulators fail to rotate. (This works fine on a device though.)

The workaround is to install the *RotateScreenOrientation.apk* which can force the emulator to be in portrait or landscape but this quickly becomes tedious if you have the option to *Wipe user data* on emulator start enabled.

Comment: Cool the `Do not keep activities` option is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks :)