# Android Simulator: Easy way to simulate a process restart due to low memory?

Tags: android, memory, process, emulation, multitasking

As I just learned, Android reserves the right to kill a background application's process at any moment in order to recycle RAM. The application is still running and can be resumed nevertheless, but all of my static variables are gone (see [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html) article).

I'd like to simulate my app's behavior in this scenario. What's the easiest way to do this? There certainly must be an easier and more predictable way than writing some additional apps that allocate lots of memory.

Comment: Does this differ from killing your own process `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`?

Comment: @tidbeck: Your guess is as good as mine. I am referring to this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to force restart service (OS killing on low memory behavior)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257378/android-how-to-force-restart-service-os-killing-on-low-memory-behavior)

Answer (score 10):

Found two similar questions [Simulate killing of activity in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5287237/562935) and [Simulate low battery & low memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3656594/562935).

Solutions from those questions:

- Use `adb shell` and then `kill` the process with `PID` from `ps`
- Kill it using [DDMS](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html)

Answer (score 6):

short answer: change orientation if you are using an emulator. if using actual device, change settings by going to settings --> developer options --> don't keep activities.

see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048149/909956) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048112/909956) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this next time I am updating my Android App.

Comment: this tests a configuration change - not a process restart. these are two different things.

Comment: Do not keep activities wont destroy the global app context, we want to be able to destroy the global app context so that at rerun it will try to start from application onCreate() and starts the last opened activity

Answer (score 3):

To kill background processes (but still relaunch via history), you can just use activity manager shell command on simulator or device:

```
$ adb shell am kill com.my.package
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to build a super basic app that calls [killBackgroundProcesses()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)) for your package, because this method "is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed."