# java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized error when using YouTubePlayerApi

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm using **YouTubePlayerAPI** and **YouTubePlayerSupportFragment** in my app and I'm getting the following error, but I couldn't find out what is causing it. I've been looking for information but I haven't found anything useful.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.l$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ad.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the stackstrace there isn't any line number pointing to any of my classes or activities.

Any idea of it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My custom **YoutubePlayerFragment** Class: `YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment.java`

```
public class YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {


private static final String ARG_URL = "url";


// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment() {
}

/**
 * Factory method to generate a new instance of the fragment given a video URL.
 *
 * @param url The video url this fragment represents
 * @return A new instance of this fragment with itemId extras
 */
public static YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment newInstance(String url) {
    final YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment mFragment = new YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment();

    // Set up extras
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_URL, url);
    mFragment.setArguments(args);

    // Initialize YouTubePlayer
    mFragment.init();

    return mFragment;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

private void init(){
    initialize(Constants.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getArguments().getString(ARG_URL));
                youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
            }
    }
}
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <!-- For YoutubeFragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

calling method:

```
// Create a new instance of YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment providing video id
        // and place it in the corresponding FrameLayout
        final YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment youTubeVideoPlayerFragment = YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment.newInstance(VIDEO_ID);
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubeVideoPlayerFragment);
        ft.commit();
```

**EDIT**

I've found out the origin of that error. This is the scenario:

The activity starts. In `onCreate()` it instantiates a new `YouTubeVideoPlayerFragment` and initializes **YouTube** object (which starts the `YouTubeServiceEntity` internally) in its `newInstance()` method. Then the `YouTube` fragment that was instantiated before, is attached with `FragmentManager` to the corresponding `FrameLayout` while video is loading.

**Here is the issue:** If user exits the activity before video had been loaded, the exception is thrown.

So if user want to exit from the activity in that case, what should I do and how? I don't really know what to do!

Comment: can you show your code where you initialized YouTubeServiceEntity

Comment: Edited with code @Zoya

Comment: Sorry but I am still unable to find the initialization of YouTubeServiceEntity. and your logcat is also reporting the same problem

Comment: Sorry! I dont directly initialize YouTubeServiceEntity. I suppose it is initialized trought the YouTubePlayerApi jar library

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this?

Comment: I'm using Youtube api and facing this error very much. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @HuyDuongTu not yet. I haven't guess how could i check if the init has finished as is answered by a user in that link: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6582

Comment: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized does that happen when you stay in the activity or when the user exits the activity?

Comment: Please take a look into this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175333

Comment: where is the actual view declared? I mean where is the YouTubePlayerView?

Comment: @paul_hundal The view is handled internally by the fragment. [Read the docs.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)

Comment: issue isn't about YouTube Android Player Fragment version. I use YouTube Android Player only with activity and have same issue:  I get some reports from Google Console `java.lang.IllegalStateException android.os.Parcel.readException`

Comment: created an issue (official repository) https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/23

Answer (score 4):

Once again, do NOT use fragment constructors or factory methods to work with lifecycle or context bound entities. Simply put, such entities can only be used after `super.onCreate(...)` has been called.

The question now is, when to call the `init` method?

Here's what [`YouTubePlayerFragment` documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) says:

> The `YouTubePlayer` associated with this fragment will be released whenever its `onDestroyView()` method is called. You will therefore have to re-call `initialize(String, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener)` whenever the activity associated with this fragment is recreated, even if the fragment instance is retained across activity re-creation by setting `setRetainInstance(boolean)`.

You may be tempted to put `init()` in `onActivityCreated` but that's too late, since `onStart` was already called and layout already performed.

Counterpart to `onDestroyView` is `onViewCreated` and that's the perfect candidate.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    init();
}
```

As suggested call `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment's constructor. When the activity is recreated the fragment will not be recreated, only its UI will go through lifecycle events.

Comment: I use only activity with YouTube player and still I get some reports from Google Console about this issue: `java.lang.IllegalStateException android.os.Parcel.readException`. So it's not about fragments (I don't use them)

Comment: I'm calling init() from onResume() still getting the crash..Any idea?

Comment: I am calling init() inside onViewCreated and get the same bug

Comment: @Duna Looks like a problem with saved state. Emulate state restoration by going to Developer Settings and check [Don't keep activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400859/dont-keep-activities-what-is-it-for) option at the end. Then start your player, press Home, then go back to your player. It should crash. Open a new SO question with the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same error reported from a Huawei cellphone.

I see an explanation here:

https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/23

Not sure if there is a way to catch the exception in our code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the initialization of the Youtube fragment. YouTubePlayerSupportFragment has to be extended in a class of yours and overrides some methods. You have to control the screen orientation and the onSaveInstanceState.

```
public class YouTubePlayerFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

  private YouTubePlayer mPlayer;

  public static YouTubePlayerFragment newInstance() {
    return new YouTubePlayerFragment();
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    setRetainInstance(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(String s, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener) {
    super.initialize(s, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
      @Override public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
      YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        mPlayer = youTubePlayer;

        onInitializedListener.onInitializationSuccess(provider, youTubePlayer, b);
      }

      @Override public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
      YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        onInitializedListener.onInitializationFailure(provider, youTubeInitializationResult);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override public void onDestroyView() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {

      mPlayer.release();
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
  }

  public YouTubePlayer getPlayer() {
    return mPlayer;
  }
}
```

YoutubeFragment.class

```
      public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String EXTRA_PLAYED_VIDEO = "EXTRA_PLAYED_VIDEO";
    private static final String EXTRA_IS_PLAYING = "EXTRA_IS_PLAYING";
    private static final String YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT = "YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String EXTRA_YOUTUBE_ID = "EXTRA_YOUTUBE_ID";

    private RelativeLayout youtubeLayoutContainer;

    private String youtubeId;
    private int playedVideo;
    private boolean isPlaying;

    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener =
        new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

          @Override
          public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
              boolean wasRestored) {

            if (!wasRestored) {
              setYouTubePlayer(player);
            }
          }

          @Override public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
              YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
          }
        };

    public static YoutubeFragment newInstance(String youtubeId) {
      YoutubeFragment youtubeElements = new YoutubeFragment();

      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString(EXTRA_YOUTUBE_ID, youtubeId);
      youtubeElements.setArguments(bundle);

      return youtubeElements;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Nullable @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_youtube_elements_item, container, false);

      initViews(mView);

      initYoutubeFragment();

      return mView;
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
      youtubeLayoutContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeLayoutContainer);

      youtubeLayoutContainer.getViewTreeObserver()
          .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) @Override public void onGlobalLayout() {
              FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                  new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

              youtubeLayoutContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);
              if (AndroidSdkVersion.hasJellyBean16()) {
                youtubeLayoutContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
              }
            }
          });
    }

    private void initYoutubeFragment() {
      try {
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment2 = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
        youTubePlayerFragment2.initialize(BuildConfig.YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY, onInitializedListener);

        if (this.getActivity() != null && !this.getActivity().isFinishing()) {
          getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.youtubePlayerFragmentContent, youTubePlayerFragment2, YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT)
              .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
      }
    }

    public void setYouTubePlayer(final YouTubePlayer player) {
      try {
        if (player == null) {
          return;
        }

        player.setShowFullscreenButton(true);
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

        if (playedVideo >= 0) {
          if (playedVideo == 0 || isPlaying) {
            player.loadVideo(youtubeId, playedVideo);
          } else {
            player.cueVideo(youtubeId, playedVideo);
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
      }
    }

    @Override public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        playedVideo = savedInstanceState.getInt(EXTRA_PLAYED_VIDEO);
        isPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_PLAYING);
      }
    }

    @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      try {
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment =
            (YouTubePlayerFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT);
        YouTubePlayer mPlayer = youTubePlayerSupportFragment.getPlayer();

        if (mPlayer != null) {
          outState.putInt(EXTRA_PLAYED_VIDEO, mPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
          outState.putBoolean(EXTRA_IS_PLAYING, mPlayer.isPlaying());
        }
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
      }

      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
  }
```

Activity containing Youtube Fragment

```
public class YoutubeContentDataActivity extends BaseActivity {

      private static final String EXTRA_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = "EXTRA_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID";
      private static final String TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT = "TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT";

      public static void open(Context context, String videoId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YoutubeContentDataActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }

      @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_main_container_layout);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        YoutubeFragment youtubeElementsFragment =
            (YoutubeFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT);

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (youtubeElementsFragment == null) {

          String videoId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
          // videoId = "17uHCHfgs60";//"ikO91fQBsTQ";
          youtubeElementsFragment = YoutubeFragment.newInstance(videoId);
          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.youtube_main_container, youtubeElementsFragment, TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT)
              .commit();
        }
      }

      @Override public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (isFinishing()) {
          FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

          YoutubeFragment youtubeElementsFragment =
              (YoutubeFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT);

          fm.beginTransaction().remove(youtubeElementsFragment).commit();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with fragments, cause I have this issue using only activity: https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/23

Comment: I have restricted change in screen orientation, still I'm getting this crash..Any idea?