# I'm using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and found the following error. So far, no reliable solutions

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
The YouTubePlayerApi we're using is v1.2.2.
The crashlytics rate from Fabric:

- Galaxy J1(2016)50%
- Galaxy J1 Mini25%
- Galaxy J1 Ace25%

and Operating Systems:
5.1.1 80%, 5.1 20%

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1610)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1555)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.l$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Comment: crashing due to fragment/activity is leaking service connection with YouTube player ..

Comment: similar issue even with activity sample: https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/23

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer following StackOverflow links may be you will get help:

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized error when using YouTubePlayerApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579834/java-lang-illegalstateexception-youtubeserviceentity-not-initialized-error-when)

[Android: How to properly initialize YouTube Player inside activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946228/android-how-to-properly-initialize-youtube-player-inside-activity)