# How to make simulate time passing in phone

Tags: android

I want to test if a service will still run after lets say, 5 days has passed. I do not want to just set the phone's time, I want the phone to think that the time has passed so that it will get rid of background apps, etc.

How do I do that in adb?

Comment: but, what `5 days has passed` in programming means? if it is exactly 5 natural days, then we can not fake. if it is not, what exactly you want.

Comment: I want the Android system to kill inactive background apps.

Comment: than just kill it with `adb shell kill`

Answer (score 0):

> I want the phone to think that the time has passed so that it will
>   get rid of background apps, etc.

- Android can actually finish your application only and not other app.
- To get rid of background apps, you can use Task Manager but that's what manual process.
- If you have background service running over 5 days, you can actually stop your service, use AlarmManager for it.

As your question is not properly clarified, there could be multiple solution to your problem, of which i have tried to address.

Comment: That is not the point. I want to speed up the time so that Android kills inactive apps.

Comment: Most likely, this can not be achieved, as in Android system, it kills app if running in background and system is in resource crunch.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it by adb?

Comment: you could try with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400859/dont-keep-activities-what-is-it-for

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my app to get the current date:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    AndroidDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Now with that said, all you can do is set the AndroidExpiryDate (string) and set your own date of expiry:

```
AndroidExpiryDate = "2016-02-28"
```

Then you can just compare current date (AndroidDate) with expiry date (AndroidExpiryDate ) using if statement:

```
if ("AndroidDate".equals("AndroidExpiryDate") )
{
    //code to get rid of background app
}
```

Comment: My intention was to test if the app/service will survive after Android kills background apps and services.