# Can a stopped Activity which belong to a foreground task be destroyed by the system?

Tags: android, android-activity

From [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> When Activity A starts Activity B, Activity A is stopped, but the
>   system retains its state (such as scroll position and text entered
>   into forms). If the user presses the Back button while in Activity B,
>   Activity A resumes with its state restored.

Activity A is not destroyed at this point. However, if one set developers option "don't keep activities" on, Activity A will be destroyed and when the user press back button in Activity B, Activity A will be recreated.

Also from [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> Note: Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However,
>   if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the
>   system might begin destroying background activities in order to
>   recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost.

As far as I know, "don't keep activities" is useful because it helps recreate the situation in which the os kills your app process when it's in background.

Is it possible (with "don't keep activities" off) that Activity A gets destroyed by the os while Activity B is visible in foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario in which the foreground task's process is terminated is if, in multi-window mode, your task is in one window, and the user in another window goes into Settings and removes some permission grant. However, at that point, the whole process is gone; Activity B would have been visible in the foreground up to that point, but then is gone.

And, if device undergoes a configuration change while Activity B is in the foreground, then presses BACK or otherwise navigates to Activity A, by default Activity A will be destroyed and recreated... but at that point, Activity B is no longer in the foreground.

And, of course, *you* can cause Activity A to be destroyed by calling `finish()` on it.

Hence, given my interpretation of your question, the answer is "no, if you are not calling `finish()`, Activity A will not be destroyed while Activity B is still in the foreground".

Comment: thanks for the input, do you know why the docs say "the system might begin destroying background activities", does it mean it can destroy single activities? or can it only destroy entire stacks?

Comment: @lelloman: "does it mean it can destroy single activities?" -- Android terminates processes. It may destroy activities as part of doing that, or just terminate the process without calling `onDestroy()` on running components (it depends on circumstances). Technically, terminating processes has no impact at all on tasks. So, one scenario that I forgot in my answer would be if Activity A and Activity B are in separate processes, if Activity B is in the foreground, there is no guarantee that Activity A's process will stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Does it?  No.  Is it allowed to?  Yes.

Android *currently* does not destroy activities in the backstack without destroying the entire process.  However, the docs suggest that it could.  As the Android developers have shown no compunction about making changes that cause massive breakage of apps that do not follow the guidelines in the documentation (e.g., the introduction of `NetworkOnMainThreadException`) I think it's good practice to rigorously test your apps with Don't Keep Activities on.

Comment: thanks for the input, you sold me with the NetworkOnMainThreadException example

Answer (score 0):

After starting the intent, do a finish(). This will run the onDestroy method for the activity.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible (with "don't keep activities" off) that Activity A gets
>   destroyed by the os while Activity B is visible in foreground?

Yes, as long as an `Activity` is not in the foreground; Then, there will be a chance to be killed by the OS due to low memory.

During development, the way to simulate this behavior (Your Activity A being killed by OS) is to enable the ***Don't keep activities*** in the developer option.

Comment: thanks for the input, is this your interpretation of the docs quote I posted or do you have any other evidence?

Comment: I use that practice to check my application during development. Normally, the OS wont kill your Activity A immediately. If you print a log in the lifecycle, when u start Activity B, your Activity A onStop() will be called. But, with 'Dont keep activities' enabled, your Activity A onDestroy() will be called immediately after onStop(). onDestory() will only be called if an activity is going to be destroyed completely. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Comment: @user2234894: No, Android terminates processes to free up system RAM. If Activity B is in the foreground, its process will not be terminated to free up system RAM (unless the device is very very sick).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll assume both activity run in the same process (multiprocess=false). From what I understand is, the OS will kill other processes first. Until the last option, the OS will only start to kill those Activity that are not in the foreground. But still, there is possibility of  Activity A get killed by the OS while Activity B is in the foreground. Am I understood it correctly?

Comment: @user2234894: Sorry, but that is not how Android works. This was a common misconception back in 2010 and previously. [It was clarified nearly six years ago](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare That is not how Android *currently* works.  The documentation allows for the possibility that it will work that way in the future.  DKA tests against the documentation, not the implementation.

Comment: So basically this answer is wrong but it would be a good idea to make my activities behave as if it was right